# Security Exception no UOL Host

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net

Desenvolvi uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC que roda perfeitamente no local.

Ao subi-la para o UOL Host, ao acessar a página (www.manuelaibi.com.br) tenho o erro Security Exception...

É importante ressaltar que já alterei o Web.config para ter as linhas

```
<securityPolicy>
  <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
</securityPolicy>
```

na chave system web.

Toda a pesquisa que fiz não achei mais nenhuma razão para não funcionar.

Alguém teria alguma ideia, por favor?

Só para completar o conjunto de informação a stack de erro é:

[SecurityException: Request failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +96
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(Object assemblyOrString, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed) +80
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, Object assemblyOrString, SecurityAction action, Boolean throwException) +288
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.CheckSetHelper(CompressedStack cs, PermissionSet grants, PermissionSet refused, PermissionSet demands, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, RuntimeAssembly asm, SecurityAction action) +70
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +30
   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid() +12
   System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection ps) +2045
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash() +107
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDateInternal(Int64 cachedHash) +458
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(Int64 cachedHash) +51
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

Answer (score 0):

Olá, seguindo a documentação você deve adicionar as politicas de segurança corretamente.
Adicione esta linha ao seu arquivo web.config:
Segue a documentação dos níveis de [segurança possíveis](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/tkscy493(v=vs.85))
Segue a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes#knownissues) de *breaking changes*, para essa versão do .net.

```
<system.Web>
...
    <trust level="Full"/>
...
</system.Web>
```

Comment: Já está lá... Você pode ver que comentei isso na questão... Mas não está funcionando...

Comment: separe as palavras, veja como você colocou: <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/> . Deve ser da seguinte forma: <trust level="Full"/> remove o atributo policyFile="internal" , se funcionar, depois você coloca de volta.

Answer (score 0):

Quando se utiliza o atributo trustLevel name="Full" cria-se conflito com as linhas da chave system.codedom e estas devem ser comentadas para fora do Web.config

Answer (score 0):

Não adianta adicionar Trust Level, trust name ou algo do tipo pois vai bloquear do mesmo jeito.
No meu caso foi só remover o trecho abaixo do web.config:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```